# Genymotion and ReactNative: why pixelRation returns 2 instead 4 at devices with 640 dpi

Tags: react-native

For example, devices, such S6 / S7 with 640 returns pixelRatio = 2 instead of 4? And text with same size appearing double in this case in compare with devices 320 dpi.